# mv on a glob pattern does not work without sudo

Tags: shell, rename, wildcards

I am using **MySQL** database on **Ubuntu** machine.

My **MySQL** data directory is `/var/lib/mysql/` , since I have a database named "**db_test**" , so, I have a directory named `db_test/` under `/var/lib/mysql/` . And all the table info are under `/var/lib/mysql/db_test/`

```
/var/lib/mysql# ls
db_test

/var/lib/mysql# cd db_test
/var/lib/mysql/db_test# ls
cars.frm
cars.MYD
cars.MYI
customers.frm
customers.MYD
...
```

What I want to achieve is very simple, just make a new directory named "**backup**", and **move all files under** `/var/lib/mysql/db_test/` to the `/var/lib/mysql/backup/` directory. So, I run the following commands under **a sub-directory of my home directory**:

```
~/tmp$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql/backup
~/tmp$ sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/db_test/* /var/lib/mysql/backup
```

The 1st `mkdir` command run successfully, I did get a new directory named "backup/" under `/var/lib/mysql/`

**But the 2nd command get failed**, with the following error message:

```
mv: cannot stat `/var/lib/mysql/db_test/*': No such file or directory
```

Why?? I have `db_test/` directory under `/var/lib/mysql/` and many table files inside, why it raise the error message?

**P.S.** 
I know only root user can access `/var/lib/mysql/`. Could it be the reason? (but I used `sudo`), I am not sure though... and how to get rid of it?

Comment: what does `ls -A /var/lib/mysql/db_test/` output?

Comment: It output all the table files

Comment: Please check my post, I have updated the thing you ask.

Comment: What do you intend to do after you move the files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/db_test/* /var/lib/mysql/backup
```

When you type that, you user's shell tries do expand the file list for `/var/lib/mysql/db_test/*`. If your user doesn't have access to that directory, that will fail, and no substitution is done.

So the `mv` command run by `sudo` will get `/var/lib/mysql/db_test/*` as a *literal* filename. A file with such a name does not exist.

Try with:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'mv /var/lib/mysql/db_test/* /var/lib/mysql/backup'
```

But you should *really*, **really** consider using database tools to do database backups.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you do MySQL database backups. Instead you need to use `mysqldump` like so:

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_test > ~/backup/db_test.sql
```

Do not create a backup directory in the `/var/lib/mysql` directory, place it elsewhere. In the above example replace `root` with the name of the database user and db_test with the name of your database. You'll be prompted for a password which is the database user's password, not your local account's password. When it's all said and done ~/backup/db_test.sql will contain a full backup. To restore a backup you simply need to

```
mysql -u root -p db_test < ~/backup/db_test.sql
```

This will import the backup into MySQL. Again replace the aforementioned names with their respective values.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use mysqldump to backup mysql db. But I am not concern on this, I just want to figure out why mv does not work in my case. How to backup database is not the question I wanna ask. Anyhow, thank you for your answer.